How to model process with different steps
I am currently trying to model a process that has multiple sequential steps where the information and results from previous steps should be used in the prediction of later steps. As of right now I am using separate models for each step after a bit of research it appears recurrent neural networks could be a candidate but I was not able to find any implementations similar to what I want. Any algo/methodology solution should be able to do at least the following things:
make predictions at each step
evaluate performance i.e. roc_auc, lift charts etc.
interpret predictions at each step i.e. LIME/Shapley
incorporate previous data and results in later steps
The input data is tabular any suggestions would be appreciated?
